# How can I compile Qt for Android with bluetooth?

Tags: android, linux, qt, bluetooth, cross-platform

I am pretty new to Qt (and linux for that matter), but need to build an Android app based on Qt with some basic bluetooth functionality. I have been able to build Qt for Android from source and develop a simple app, but QtBluetooth cannot be found.

Starting point:

- Ubuntu 18.10 x64
- Android NDK r18b
- Android SDK (android-27)
- OpenJDK v1.8.0_212
- Qt 5.12.3

This is my configure command:

```
./configure -xplatform android-clang -android-ndk [path to NDK] -android-sdk [path to SDK] -android-ndk-host linux-x86_64 -android-toolchain-version 4.9 -no-warnings-are-errors -android-ndk-platform andoird-27 -opensource -confirm-license -v
```

The configure output shows that none of the Qt Bluetooth components are enabled, and that this is because

- "None of [libbluetooth.so libbluetooth.a] could be found in [] and global paths."
- "pkg-config use disabled globally"

This is really frustrating because I've installed those libraries: both of those files are in the /usr/lib/x86_65-linux-gnu/ directory! Also pkg-config is installed...

I have tried adding this path (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/) to the configure command and copying these libraries into directories that I would have thought are already included, but these workarounds have been fruitless. I am using git to clean the submdodules and main directory between each attempt.

What am I missing?? It feels like this is sooo close to working.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to build Qt yourself? If there's no reason, wouldn't it make more sense to use the pre-built SDK, and get your app working with that, before considering custom Qt build?

Comment: @hyde I tried that first (from Windows), and got errors due to missing compilers for Android. After being unable to resolve that issue, I tried my hand at building Qt from source on linux. It wasn't so bad, except for this bluetooth issue...

Comment: Well, did you install the compilers (Android SDK *and* NDK), ie. did you follow the installation instructions?

Comment: I did, using SDK v26 and NDK r20 (also tried r18b), but always got a message that the compilers for android were missing ("No compiler can produce code for this Qt version"). Going back to that again, I just tried updating to the latest version of Qt Creator (4.7 -> 4.9.2), and that fixed it! So I can now do my development :) But this question still stands...